# Did I derive this correctly?

Tags: calculus

I derived this $$(2x+1)^2 \sqrt{4x+1}$$
and got $(8x+4)(\sqrt{4x+1})$+$\frac{2}{\sqrt{4x+1}}(2x+1)^2$
Is this correct?

I ask because Wofram Alpha gave me a different answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks all right to me. But what is the *different* answer?

Comment: Oh I see you were taking a derivative. Yes it's correct.

Comment: @JohnCarpenter I think he means "differentiated".

Comment: @Peter Tamaroff  Yupp!

Comment: WolframAlpha made the answer more compact, like $$\frac{40x^2 + 32x + 6}{\sqrt{4x+1}}$$, then factor the top.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Wolfram Alpha gave me $\frac{2(2x+1)(10x+3)}{\sqrt{4x+1}}$

Comment: @ShuhaoCao Maybe I simplified my answer incorrectly, because I didn't get the same answer

Comment: Okay, I added an answer to address the simplification issue.

Comment: Wolfram just combined the two terms, nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer:
$$\begin{aligned}
&(8x+4)(\sqrt{4x+1})+\frac{2}{\sqrt{4x+1}}(2x+1)^2
\\
=& \frac{(8x+4)(4x+1)}{\sqrt{4x+1}}+\frac{2(2x+1)^2}{\sqrt{4x+1}}
\\
=& \frac{32x^2 + 24x + 4}{\sqrt{4x+1}} + \frac{8x^2 + 8x + 2}{\sqrt{4x+1}}
\\
=& \frac{40x^2 + 32x + 6}{\sqrt{4x+1}}
\\
=& \frac{2(10x + 3)(2x+1)}{\sqrt{4x+1}}.
\end{aligned}$$
WolframAlpha's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you derived correctly, just look at the alternate forms of your solution at [wolframalpha of your solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%288x%2b4%29%2asqrt%284x%2b1%29%20%2b%202/sqrt%284x%2b1%29%20%2a%20%282x%2b1%29%5E2)

so your solution equals the one of wolframalpha.

Answer (score 2):

Correct answer and this is the result given by Maple

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I derived it with Product Rule; your answer is correct!

Answer (score 1):

To check yourself just take the integral of that and you will come back to your original answer assuming you have learned to take an integral.

Comment: True, but that's one big integral, perhaps he isn't "there" yet as he is learning derivatives :)

Comment: Very true, well said.